# Parsing a string that has multiple Json elements without comma seperation

Tags: java, json

I have a string like:

```
{"personId":"p-111","itemId":"i-111"}{"personId":"p-222","itemId":"i-222"}{"personId":"p-333","itemId":"i-333"}
```

My pojo is:

```
ItemPurchase {
    String personId,
    String itemId
}
```

How can I get a list of ItemPurchase pojos from the string given above?

I am not able to get the list using Jackson because there is no comma seperation and no [ ] parentheses at start and end respectively to indicate that its a Json array.

Comment: Have you tried to add `[ ]` around of string and replace `"}{"` to `"},{"`?

Comment: Try with Gson Library https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 7159 section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-2) states:

> Note that certain previous specifications of JSON constrained a JSON text to be an object or an array.

Looks like your JSON parser does not expect a bunch of objects, unless they come in an array or container object.

Maybe you can upgrade (or switch) your parser, or have the producer write RFC4627-compatible JSON, or go with @ApceH Hypocrite's workaround and add enclosing square brackets and insert commas to form a legal JSON array.

Answer (score 1):

The [GSON library](https://github.com/google/gson) can handle that kind of input if setup correctly. Use [`JsonReader.setLenient(true)`](http://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#setLenient-boolean-):

```
public class Main {
  public static class ItemPurchase {
    public String name;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String input = "{\"name\":\"John\"}{\"name\":\"Jack\"}{}"; 
    Reader reader = new StringReader(input);
    JsonReader json = new JsonReader(reader);
    json.setLenient(true);
    ItemPurchase item0 = gson.fromJson(json, ItemPurchase.class);
    ItemPurchase item1 = gson.fromJson(json, ItemPurchase.class);
    ItemPurchase item2 = gson.fromJson(json, ItemPurchase.class);

    System.out.println(item0.name); // John
    System.out.println(item1.name); // Jack
    System.out.println(item2.name); // null
  }
}
```